# WCF Data Services: Why is URI needed in every datacontext, and where does this fit in a typical Layered Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am considering implementing WCF Data services in one of my projects. After extensive research, I have some questions that have yet to be answered. If someone can please help me out?

1. When we are passing concrete data specific operations (albeit over HTTP using URI's), why is a WCF data service next to the UI layer in most of the documentations? Shouldn't it be a higher level of abstraction than interfacing between UI and the EDM?
2. Why is the passing of a URI needed to establish context? Wasn't the URI passed into the ADD SERVICE REFERENCE (or DATASVCUTIL) to generate client proxy classes? Why this redundancy whenever a context needs to be established?
3. What if my service URL changes? How to determine this service URL dynamically? For example, let's assume I have a WCF DATA SERVICE at http://localhost:8443/project1/WCFSERVICE1. How can i get this URL dynamically at runtime (because of the changing port under VS)????
4. I have seen some examples where DataServiceRequest and DataServiceResponse are used; sometimes they are not and the query is directly executed via CREATEQUERY or EXECUTE. What is the difference in one line??
5. How to access a remote service over corporate network proxy? I know we can pass defaultcredentials to the webrequest but how is that to be done with wcf data service client proxy classes?

P.S. For now, I have configured a static port in visual studio. However, how to get this port dynamically?
 Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this, I'm sure by now you've got answers to most of these questions, but here goes.

Your question 3 is the answer to your title question. Passing the URI in the constructor means you have greater runtime flexibility for the location of the data service. So in my case I've got the port and server name as application settings that can be modified at runtime without the need to modify the application. 
Hope this helps.